# How to add multiple images to an existing product with the WooCommerce API

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I want to add one or more images to an existing product that already has images within WooCommerce.

```
function addImage($sku, $images){
    global $woocommerce;

    //Get id from sku
    $products = $woocommerce->get('products/?sku='. $sku);
  
    $id = $products->id;
    $image_count = count($products->images);
    

    $item_data = [
            'images' => [
            [
                'src' => $images,
                'position' => $image_count + 1,
            ],
        ],
    ];
       
    $products = $woocommerce->post('products/'.$id, $item_data);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($products);
    echo '</pre>'; 

}
```

In my code it replaces the images that the product already has but does not add to the existing ones. I tried to use positions of the images but it still doesn't add. The same thing happens with the put and get methods. Someone already managed to do this.